# Renombrar campos de Array

Tags: php, array

Tengo el siguiente código PHP

```
<?php  
$items = json_decode($result ,true);
foreach ($items['DatosContacto'] as $dataContact => $contact) {
foreach ($contact as $contactItem => $itemC) {
echo '<p>', htmlspecialchars($contactItem . ': ' . $itemC), '</p>', PHP_EOL;
}
}
?>
```

Lo cual me imprime lo siguiente:

```
NombreContacto: mail@hotmail.com
Tel1: 85656565656
Tel2:
Mail1: mail222@hotmail.com
Mail2:
TipoContacto: miContact
FechaCumple: 1982-02-26

NombreContacto: mail@des.net.mx
Tel1: 89897987978
Tel2:
Mail1: mail@desnet.mx
Mail2:
TipoContacto: Dueño
FechaCumple: 2013-02-14
```

Como verán, el `array` tiene **devuelve datos distintos con el nombre de campo similar**

Lo que deseo es que si hay mas de un valor para el campo.
Ejemplo: `nombreContacto`, este se pueda renombrar, por ejemplo, `nombreContacto2`

**ESTO IMPRIME CON VAR_DUMP**

```
string(934) "{"ClienteId":"71039","ClienteNombre":"PROVEEDORA, SA DE CV","ClienteRFC":"THUE787878","DatosContacto":[{"NombreContacto":"ventas@hotmail.com","Tel1":"898989898 88","Tel2":"","Cel1":"","Cel2":"","Mail1":"ventas@hotmail.com","Mail2":"","TipoContacto":"Compras","FechaCumple":"1982-02-26"},{"NombreContacto":"mail@desnet.mx","Tel1":"6786786788","Tel2":"","Cel1":".","Cel2":"","Mail1":"mail@desnet.mx","Mail2":"","TipoContacto":"Dueño","FechaCumple":"2013-02-14"}],"Direcciones":[{"Calle":"BLVD GHOST","Colonia":"TAMAULIPAS","Entrecalles":"SENDA DOM","CP":"89660","Municipio":"TAMPICO","Estado":"TAMAULIPAS","Pais":"Mexico"},{"Calle":"BLVD. EMILIO PORTES GIL #550","Colonia":"GUADALUPE MAINERO","Entrecalles":"CON CARRANZA","CP":"66667","Municipio":"TAMPICO","Estado":"TAMAULIPAS","Pais":"Mexico"}],"DatosCompras":{"LimiteCredito":"0.00","DiasCredito":0,"DescuentoAutorizado":0}} "
```

Comment: ¿De dónde vienen esos datos y por qué no vienen ya del modo esperado desde el origen? ¿Quizá no hay que optimizar en otro punto de tu programa?

Comment: Y, si son datos de personas distintas, ¿por qué no los organizas como array de objetos JSON, algo así: `[{un grupo de datos}, {otro grupo de datos}, {otro grupo de datos}]`? Hacer otros tipos de estructuras te podría dificultar la lectura final de los datos.

Comment: la recibo de un webService, pero es lo que ando pensando (solicitar me envien la info. De esa manera)

Comment: Puede que el WS ya la envíe así y que tú estés queriendo complicarte la vida. ¿Podrías mostrarnos lo que imprime un `var_dump($result);` sin más? Si es muy largo pulsa en [edit]  y agrégalo a la pregunta **como texto** e identado si es posible. Los WebService suelen ser programas bien diseñados que ofrecen los datos para ser consumidos de la mejor manera posible.

Comment: Entonces, ya tienes en la clave  `DatosContacto` el objeto organizado como un array, ¿por qué quieres manipularlo ahora cambiando nombres de clave? Lo propio sería leer los datos en un bucle.

Comment: Y COMO REALIZO ESO,  ya que deseo asignar tales direcciones a un formulario de registro, pero dichos valores deben ir asignados a campos especificos

Comment: @DevDark ¿Quisieras que dijera `NombreContacto [x]: valor`? Donde `[x]` es el índice del item en el arreglo

Comment: $calle=$items['Direcciones'][0]['Calle'];
$entrecalle=$items['Direcciones'][0]['Entrecalles'];
$colonia=$items['Direcciones'][0]['Colonia'];
$calle2=$items['Direcciones'][1]['Calle'];
$entrecalle2=$items['Direcciones'][1]['Entrecalles'];
$colonia2=$items['Direcciones'][1]['Colonia'];                                                                               Lo he solucionado de esa manera

Answer (score 0):

Generalmente los datos que se sirven en Web Services y en APIs son acorde a una regla de negocio, por lo que vienen listos para ser consumidos de una forma fácil.

No tiene mucho sentido querer modificar los nombres de clave de esos datos. Además, si modificas la respuesta original puede que la lectura posterior del objeto sea bastante complicada.

Conforme a la estructura que muestras en el `var_dump`, en la respuesta habría un arreglo de objetos JSON dentro de la clave `DatosContacto` que podrías leer fácilmente del siguiente modo:

```
#Creamos un json con la respuesta del WS
$json=json_decode($result);

#NOTESE que arriba no pusimos TRUE
#Esto permite tratar a $json como objeto
#y leerlo usando la notación $objeto->propiedad sin más
#lo cual es más claro e intuitivo...

foreach ($json->DatosContacto as $dato){
    echo $dato->NombreContacto.PHP_EOL;
    echo $dato->Tel1.PHP_EOL;
    echo PHP_EOL;
    #... puedes obtener cada valor por su nombre de clave
}
```

**Salida:**

```
ventas@hotmail.com
898989898 88

mail@desnet.mx
6786786788
```

O, si quieres leer todas las propiedades valores del objeto:

```
foreach ($json->DatosContacto as $dato){
    foreach ($dato as $k=>$v){
        echo "$k : $v".PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Salida:**

```
NombreContacto : ventas@hotmail.com
Tel1 : 898989898 88
Tel2 : 
Cel1 : 
Cel2 : 
Mail1 : ventas@hotmail.com
Mail2 : 
TipoContacto : Compras
FechaCumple : 1982-02-26

NombreContacto : mail@desnet.mx
Tel1 : 6786786788
Tel2 : 
Cel1 : .
Cel2 : 
Mail1 : mail@desnet.mx
Mail2 : 
TipoContacto : Dueño
FechaCumple : 2013-02-14
```

Así cómo lees la parte de la respuesta relativa a `DatosContacto`, puedes leer las otras, como `DatosCompras`, conforme a su estructura. Como dije más arriba, los WS y las APIs se programan para una lectura conforme a unas reglas, no para tener luego que re-inventar la rueda.

Comment: Eso ya lo obtengo, (como mencioné, estos datos, serán para llenar un formulario), sin embargo, supongamos que el primer conjunto de datos sean para cliente y el segundo conjunto sea para vendedor,    ¿Cómo logro asignar respectivamente tales valores?  PD: Gracias de antemano.

Comment: echo  $items['DatosContacto'][0]['NombreContacto'];
 echo  $items['DatosContacto'][1]['NombreContacto'];

Comment: Lo he solucionado, (Es lo que buscaba)  Gracias por el tiempo

Comment: @DevDark supongo que habrá alguna forma de saberlo. ¿Acaso por la clave `TipoContacto`? De ser por esa clave simplemente preguntarías `if($dato->Tipo contacto==="Dueño") { //llenar el área de dueño } else { //llenar el área de compras}`. Vuelvo a lo mismo, los WS se programan en base a reglas por lo que deben tener la información que requieres para tomar decisiones en el código de una forma simple.

Comment: Si los has obtenido por los índices `0` y `1` significa entonces que en ese caso la regla definida es que en el índice `0` vendrían los datos para cliente y en el índice `1` los datos para vendedor. Repito otra vez lo mismo, conociendo la regla en que se produce la respuesta del WebService deberías lograr fácilmente lo que quieres sin tener que reinventar la rueda renombrado claves y cosas por el estilo.